# Checking for NSURL load done

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm looking for a "did finish, or finish" thing in NSURL ->  NSstring initWithContentsOfUrl

I found "URLResourceDidFinishLoading" but this seems to be depreciated

I couldn't find any but maybe I searched for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about `-initWithContentsOfURL:` from `NSString`, it has been [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html).

But even if you are using it, it's a synchronous method - meaning your code will halt until the data has been loaded into the resulting `NSString` object:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSString *htmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"%@", htmlData); // you have your data loaded here, synchronously.
```

So, just to be clear: this is a **bad practice** for two reasons:

1. You're using a deprecated method which will most likely be removed on future SDK versions, and;
2. You're freezing your UI while loading something from the network, while giving no feedback to the user whatsoever.

What you need is probably [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create your request object and [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to actually load it from the network.

Comment: thanks, good to know.
i haven't seen that "initWithContentsOfURL" has also been deprecated
exactly what i'm looking for.